# Wallet Address recovery from Mist

Tags: mist, wallets, addresses, recovery

EDIT #2: I believe this actually may be a non-issue after all. Am I wrong to believe that the DTH will use a contract to withdraw the ETC and in order to avoid duplication of addresses on both ETC and ETH chain that it would have to be withdrawn to an entirely new address on the ETC chain? Therefore, all I would need to do is decrypt my address using my password - similar to the ETH withdrawn from the DAO, but this time, there will be added functionality to send it to a particular address, instead of the address where the DAO tokens were purchased and held?

EDIT: I'm happy to donate 10% of my ETC holdings that is released from the DAO if you can help me release the funds. That 10% would be somewhere around 345-360 ETC. My plan is to cash out immediately and convert to ETH.

I decided to "clean" up any unused addresses that displayed within my Mist Wallet and ended up deleting an address that I used for the DAO. On August 30th ETC will be able to be retrieved for DTHs, is it possible for me to get this wallet address back in Mist?

To clarify, I do not have a backup of the key file anywhere. I do however know the address and the type in password that I used to create the address via Mist.

Also, I've done this several weeks ago and do not believe I have windows recovery going back that far.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need the file. 

Comment: Sorry for your loss. You need the private key - is there any way for you to retrieve it? Data recovery perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

No, you're screwed. Knowing the public address and the password is useless. You have to provide the private key, clear or encrypted. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have the keyfile or the password, you cannot recover the address. Ethereum derives the address from the public key in your keyfile. Your private key for the address is also stored in an encrypted form within the keyfile. So, without your keyfile the value in your address is permanently lost.

http://www.ethdocs.org/en/latest/account-management.html#keyfiles